# Creating Connect4 in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an Android app to play Connect 4 (Four In A Row, etc). As I'm new to Android dev I created a basic Java application to cope with the logic, which plays connect4 using a 2D array and just uses *println* to print the array to the console which shows the board.

My question is in my game activity what would be the best way to create a 'board' and have it so I can update it to show the position of counters throughout the game; should I create a canvas object, butcher a table layout, or do something else entirely.

Apologies if this is a silly question; I have very limited Android experience.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed, as 4x4 grid could work if that is what you want since you have limited android experience. You can really make a board/grid in multiple ways. I would suggest making sure you know a little about the UI and the android activity lifecycle before you start diving into something. Eventually you will like to add additional UI elements such as score, player's turn etc.

UI:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Lifecycle:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Here is a grid tutorial instead of opening another view, just update the one with a piece/color or whatever
GridView tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

As the board is always the same (4x4) you could use a GridLayout with 4 cols and 4 rows. Put an ImageView in every cell and modify it following the players touches.

Comment: i am also looking forward to make such app (connect4 ) for just getting my hands onto android .
I have 2 questions to ask which i found pinching when i sat to program that up: 
1)if i want to make 6x7 grid for connect4 , do i have to include  42 grid elements in that and modify them when clicked, or is there a more efficient way rather than hard coding those 42 grid items or buttons ?

2) how do i determine when a player has won a match .

NOTE: here i am only asking for an approach or just a way , i would be happy to code myself .

Comment: hi @SyedHissaan, for the grid just use a RecyclerView. You must have a cell item and populate the RecyclerView with it. In order to determine when a player won a match you could maintain a matrix in a variable with the current estate of the match and check it after every change.